# New record not showing on Form

Tags: database, forms, field, ms-access-2013

I have a grant database with about 50 previously entered grant records.  I had to completely rebuild all the forms, queries and reports that go with the database.

I have a small form with a drop down that allows you select an existing record by grant number. Once selected, a more detailed form opens to that record and allows you to add more information to the grant record. This all works as it is supposed to.

However, on both the small drop down and the larger forms, there is an option to add a NEW grant, which opens the larger form to a blank record.  I can enter all the information for the new grant, and hit Save. Let's say I want to go back in and add more information. I click on the option to Open a Grant and the small form with the drop down list of grants comes up, I scroll down and the NEW grant I just entered is there, but when I select it and the larger form opens, the record is blank...but it's not...

If I try to re-enter the information and hit Save, I get an error that I am trying to enter duplicate information. If I open the master database, the new record and all the information I had previously entered is there.  For some reason, on any NEW record, when I select to open it, the data is not displaying in the form (the data is there, looking in the database confirms it, but all the fields on the form are blank). This only happens with new records I try to open, not with existing records.

Any ideas?

```
Private Sub cmdNewGrant_Click() 
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm_Grant", acSaveNo 
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Grant", , , , acFormAdd 
End Sub 
Private Sub cmdSaveGrant_Click() 
    DoCmd.Save MsgBox "Your new grant has been saved." 
End Sub
```

Comment: If you add a new grant, then exit and reopen the database, does the data now show up?

Comment: Do you requery your 'drop-down', and any other controls / recordsets that may be involved? I assume you don't have some code that tells the form to open in 'add mode'?

Comment: Alan - The data still does not show up after exit and reopen.

Comment: Wayne - Here is my code to open the form, and to save the form, unfortunately, not sure how to "re-query":                                            Private Sub cmdNewGrant_Click()
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm_Grant", acSaveNo
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Grant", , , , acFormAdd                             End Sub
Private Sub cmdSaveGrant_Click()
    DoCmd.Save
    MsgBox "Your new grant has been saved."
End Sub

Comment: (1) Where is the code you use when you select item from drop-down? (2) Where is code from when you 'hit Save'? (3) What do you expect to happen in cmdSaveGrant_Click? If you are trying to save the record, you should use:  DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord (4) Which form(s) is/are the code you provided above located in?

Comment: Drop down code: Private Sub cmdGoToGrant_Click()
'If Not IsNull(Me.txtUserName) Then
'If DCount("GrantNumber", "tbl_grantinfo", "[grantnumber] = '" & Forms![enter grant number]![GrantNumber] & "'") > 0 Then
DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_grant", , , "[grantnumber]='" & Forms![frm_GrantNumber]![GrantNumber] & "'", acFormEdit
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm_GrantNumber", acSaveNo
'Else
'DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_NewGrant"
'End If
'End If
End Sub
Private Sub cmdNewGrant_Click()
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm_Grant", acSaveNo
DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Grant", , , , acFormAdd
End Sub

Comment: Data Entry Form code: This is the code for the data entry form: 
Private Sub cmdNewGrant_GotFocus()
DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Grant"
Forms!frm_Grant.Requery
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
End Sub
Private Sub cmdSaveGrant_Click()
DoCmd.Save
Me.Requery
MsgBox "Your new grant has been saved."
End Sub
'Open grant number dialog box to enter new grant or select a different grant
Private Sub cmdNewGrant_Click()
DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_grantnumber", , , , , acDialog
End Sub
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm_GrantNumber", acSaveNo
End Sub

Comment: Anyone have any idea's?  I'd be happy to share the database using google drive or something similar.

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed?